# How to code - 'Date' comparison in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

I'm a beginner in Alloy. This is my first model using Alloy Analyzer. I'm now building a generic model for Travel in Alloy. In this model, a user (I use sig Request in this model) can make a request for 'accommodation' (includes 'hotel' or 'apartment' or 'hostel'); 'flight'; or 'tour', (the request can be either one of them or any combination of them, for example hotel and tour). Each of them is subset of 'resource'. For now, I stick the request for one destination only, and check-in & check-out date for accommodation as well as inbound-date & outbound-date for flight must be the same as begin-date & end-date for user request.

My questions as follows:

1. Firstly, in order to ensure check-in, check-out, inbound, and outbound date are the same as as begin-date & end-date for user request, all of them is mapped to beginning_of_journey and end_of_journey (please see the codes). Is this the correct way?
2. Secondly, I have a problem on how to code the constraint - tour date must  be within begin-date and end-date of user request (so that the tour date must be within check-in, inbound, check-out, and outbound date as well).  I define a set Date (sig Date) that has the fields day, month, and year where each of them has been defined as Integer. However, the problem is day can be negative number. And after executing the codes, the given instance seems weird. Could anyone please give a suggestion or advise me the right way to define that constraint?
3. Thirdly, I have a question that need to be clarified. Let say, the above problem has been resolved, and I need to initialise the specific request, for example tour date is July 1, 2016, date-begin is July 2, 2016 and end-date is July 4, 2016. Since I have defined the above constrained (Question No. 2), I want Alloy informs that the date given are violated. Is it possible to Alloy to do that?

I would really appreciate if anyone could give some comments and advice. Thank you

Comment: The use of Int is very limited in Alloy and I would discourage it in this case.
What you can do instead is to define an ordering on Date (util/ordering[Date]) to allow comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test dates for sameness and for order.  Unless you are trying to check the correctness of a design for calculating sameness and order of dates in the Gregorian calendar, however, there seems to be very little utility to modeling the internal structure of dates in Alloy.

So in your position I would, as Loïc Gammaitoni has already suggested, define an ordering on Date to support your queries on sequence.